# Keeping colors on an image while setting full transparency

Tags: gimp, transparency, png

I would like to create an image from a map, where each country is colored in a different color, where the frontiers are in black, and in which each color except black is fully transparent, while not losing the RGB information.

My tools are The Gimp or anything installable on Linux, and small scale programming (if I need to fully understand the png format, I won't succeed).

My current image is perfect, except for the transparency information. My current experiments with GIMP have always resulted in RGB information being lost when exporting the image to png or gif.

Any pointers? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If alpha is 0 there is no RGB information in png or gif formats. What you are asking is not possible.

Comment: I wouldn't dare confront anyone on such matters, as my knowledge is practically null; yet, I would like to ask you if you are reasonably sure of that, or sure without a doubt, so that I don't spend any more time on this trail of thought. Thanks and best regards in any which case.

Comment: Would it be possible to set a 99.9% transparence, and keep RGB info?

Comment: To better understand your needs: How would you use such an image? E.g. in a program you write, or for a web page?

Comment: in a javascript webpage/program. I elected to keep a copy of the imagedata in memory, and output another transparent copy to the html 5 canvas I use. Then I do the checks on the memory copy, as any attempt to set a high transparency on the canvas, then doing pixel color checks on the canvas leads to failures too. It would be easier if all this work were done in the image to start with, but I can live with 10 lines of code, if not.

Comment: I'm positive that alpha at 100% = no RGB data in PNG and GIF formats. Including RGB data which is *never* visible in the image would unnecessarily increase the file size. Therefore the formats throw away the useless data. But yes Alpha at 99.9% would retain RGB data, even at .1% opacity.

Comment: GIMP has an option for that in the export PNG dialog, and I had coded the feature myself back in the time. So even if the specs say the color should not be there, it is for GIMP saved files with the "Save colour values from transparent pixels" option set when exporting the PNG.For gif files, the transparency is given by an specific (and only) color index, so the color information is indeed lost.

Comment: @Scott For GIF and palleted PNG this is correct as a single palette entry is deemed the "transparent color", however for 32-bit PNG images every pixel is stored as 4 bytes for R,G,B,A - even if A is 0 there can be values given for the R,G,B otherwise the data wouldn't be aligned and it would be significantly harder to read. Most programs will set these bytes to all 0 to increase the compression ratio, but this is not necessary for a valid PNG image.

Answer (score 4):

On the GIMP Export dialog for PNG files, there is a checkbox that says "Save colour values from transparent pixels".  I haven't tested it, but that should do what you want.

There doesn't seem to be an equivalent option for GIF.

More on export file format options:
http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-images-out.html#gimp-using-fileformats-export-dialog

Comment: Yes, that should do it, regardless of @Scott's comments.